# Message in Fancybox popup generated by PHP

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I would like to achieve rather simple thing I guess but I'm unable to figure out how to do it.
I need to have a message that pops out in a jQuery Fancybox window after being generated by PHP.

The code that would show the message could be that simple:

```
if(something){
    echo 'message sent!';
}
```

In this case I would want the "Message sent!" text to appear in Fancybox window.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are using fancybox v2.x and that you have properly initialized jQuery and fancybox files in your php document, I would do:

```
<?php        
    if(something) { 
      $message = "message sent!";
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.fancybox("<?php echo $message; ?>",{
            minWidth: 'auto',
            minHeight: 'auto'
        }); // fancybox
    }); // ready
</script>

<?php 
    }; // close php if
?>
```